# How can cmake activate "Inherit from parent" link option in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, clang++

I am using cmake to generate the Windows/VisualStudio solution of a multi-platform C++ project.

In VS, when I click on the project's *Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> Edit*, there is a list with dependencies I have added with cmake, that is fine. But there is also a checkbox to "**Inherit from parent of project defaults**". When cmake generate the solution this checkbox is off, but I need to check it to be able to link.

Is there a way to make cmake generate a VS project with this checkbox checked, by any chance ?

Edit : The projet is compiled with clang++.

Comment: If you need the inherit from project defaults and your entire build is made with CMake, it implies that you are missing CMake commands that are specifying the stuff you need.  Why do you need to do this?  CMake's project builder for VS assumes that everything you specified in your CMakeLists.txt is what you need and nothing more.  This prevents surprises in your build that make it only work on specific environments.

Comment: You are right in general, our cmake scripts usually generate everything fine. But in this case, we are building the same project for a new, specific, environment of a client. This client provides a plug-in for VS, frequently updated, that configures all as necessary ; but it requires this option to be checked.

Comment: You could probably find a way to run a script to get the options dumped out, but probably not much better than the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried something else and it worked fine for me.

In my top ".cmake" file I set various options, calling `add_compile_options(...)` or setting `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` for example. I have added at the end of this file the following line :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "$(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES) %(AdditionalDependencies) ")
```

It appends "`;%(AdditionalDependencies)`" at the end of the `<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>` data, without a "`.a`" or a "`.lib`" suffix that prevented link to complete in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Checking this box appends `%(AdditionalDependencies)` into the list of additional dependencies. You can set the `LINK_LIBRARIES` property of your target to add this 'manually':

```
set_target_properties(<target> PROPERTIES LINK_LIBRARIES "%(AdditionalDependencies)")
```

You may need to get this the `LINK_LIBRARIES` property and append this, depending on how you build your dependencies list. Note that trying to use the normal command `target_link_libraries` doesn't work, because CMake is unsure how to process the request, as it starts with a `%`. Also, when showing up in the IDE, it will actually add `%(AdditionalDependencies).lib`, but it still works as intended.

Comment: When I attempt to use this code, I get the following error message at cmake execution (but cmake still generates a project) : 
`Target "MyApplication" links to item " %(AdditionalDependencies)" which has leading or trailing whitespace.  This is now an error according to policy CMP0004.`

Comment: By the way, I would need indeed to append this to the LINK_LIBRARIES information I currently provide with target_link_libraries. Is there a way to keep both ?

Comment: Looks like may you just have a space before the text? It doesn't complain in my CMake (v3.8). Also, you can call `get_target_property(... LINK_LIBRARIES)` to get the current value, and just append it before calling `set_target_properties`.

Comment: Yes, the space bar is from an attempt to concatenate, my bad. Anyway, when I try to retrieve the LINK_LIBRARIES value, concatenate it with additional dependencies, and then set it back again, it acts exactly as if target_link_libraries was never performed before :/...

Comment: I could not make it work with set_target_properties : it was adding %(AdditionalDependencies).a but erasing the other libraries to link. I managed to get a similar result by adding "%(AdditionalDependencies)" (with quotes) in the middle of my target_link_libraries list of libraries (without quotes) ; the result is everything present in VS properties window, just with .a instead of .lib for AdditionalDependencies "fake" library. The checkbox is not checked but grayed out and inaccessible, which might be fine ? Alas, linking fails with `clang++.exe : error : no such file or directory: '.a'`